# MAC address boot script 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

I would like to change the mac address on boot. How does one randomize or set a particular MAC address in Ubuntu 16.04? I have searched but other threads are for older versions of Ubuntu and don't seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: You can set a MAC address in Network Manager.

Comment: Yes. However I would like to have the MAC address set at boot. Plus I am led to believe that Network Manager resets the MAC address when connecting.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from th great .

I hope this helps someone else

> As noted in the Ubuntu Forum guide, Network Manager resets changes
>   made by macchnager. Did you know that as of Network Manager 1.4, you
>   can generate a random MAC address upon each connection?
>
> Ubuntu 16.04 has Network Manager 1.2 unfortunately. You can replace it
>   with wicd. To change MAC address at startup, you can create a systemd
>   service file.
>
> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/macspoof.service
>
> Put the following text into the file. Replace %i with your network
>   interface name.
>
> [Unit] Description=macchanger on %i Wants=network-pre.target
>   Before=network-pre.target BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
>   After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
>
> [Service] ExecStart=/usr/bin/macchanger -e %i Type=oneshot
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
>
> Save and close the file. Then enable this service.
>
> sudo systemctl enable macspoof.service
>
> Restart your computer and you will have a spoofed MAC address.